# Input redirection and pipes

Tags: c, redirect, pipe, execvp

I understand piping where you want to run a command like ls -l | wc -l:

```
int pipes[2];
pipe(pipes); 

if (fork() == 0){ //first fork
  dup2(pipes[1],1); 
  close(pipes[0]);
  close(pipes[1]);

  execvp(arr1[0], arr1); //arr1[0] = "ls" and  arr1[1] = "-l" and arr1[2] = 0
  perror("Ex failed");
  exit(1);
}

if (fork() == 0){ //2nd fork
  close(pipes[1]);
  dup2(pipes[0],0); 
  close(pipes[0]);

  execvp(arr2[0], arr2); //arr2[0] = "wc" and  arr2[1] = "-l" and arr2[2] = 0
  perror("Ex failed");
  exit(1);
}
```

But, how would you include input and output redirection? lets say I want to cat < foo.txt | wc -l

I understand the first fork needs to be modified, but I don't understand what is needed (another dup2()?). I would greatly appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish with `dup2(pipes[1],[1]);`? This is invalid syntax; I take it you meant `dup2(pipes[1], STDOUT_FILENO);`?

Comment: That was a typo. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

> But, how would you include input and output redirection? lets say I
>   want to cat < foo.txt | wc -l

In the case of input redirection, you open the file for reading, and then use `dup2(2)` to duplicate the file descriptor into standard input. The file descriptor of `stdin` is `STDIN_FILENO`, defined in `unistd.h`. So, something like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// ...

filename = "foo.txt";
int fd;
if ((fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
    perror("open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO) == -1) {
    perror("dup2: %s -> stdin: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (close(fd) == -1) {
    perror("close %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Now, reading from stdin will read from the file.
// Do the normal pipe operations here.

int pipes[2];
// ...
```

Note that your code doesn't have error handling - not one - this is very bad because when something goes wrong, you will ignore it and the code will crash in mysterious ways. Pretty much every function you called can return with an error; considering handling the error to clearly show to the user what went wrong where.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  I did exactly as you advised. Open(), dup2() and close then my two forks unchanged. Is there no additional code required in the forks?

Comment: @user5832523 the code for forking should remain unchanged. Please post the full working,  compilable code that you claim is not working.